# In journal submission guidelines, what is meant by "interventions in contemporary debates"?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, philosophy

In their submission guidelines, the editors of the philosophy journal *Philosopher's Imprint* write:

> Submissions to the Imprint are refereed anonymously and selected for publication on the basis of their estimated long-term significance. The Imprint publishes articles that engage directly with a philosophical issue or historical figure. **We do not publish "interventions" in contemporary debates** or commentaries on contemporary figures. (my emphasis, [Source](https://www.philosophersimprint.org/about.html#criteria))

I want to get a better understanding of what this means, and in particular what definition of "intervention" is used here.

Surely, a paper like "in debate D, there is an error E in the paper P, and my paper does nothing else than comment on E." falls under "intervention". But is that the only kind of paper?

What the editors of the *Imprint* can't be meaning is that they wont publish any contribution to a currently ongoing debate. For example, here's an excerpt from last year:

> [...] Several philosophers (e.g. Elga 2010, Titelbaum 2015) have argued that some epistemic rules are indefeasible. I will argue that all epistemic rules are defeasible. [...] ([Source](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/p/phimp/3521354.0019.003/--are-there-indefeasible-epistemic-rules))

So, when will a contribution to an ongoing debate be considered an "intervention"? Could it be understood in terms of "not being original research"?

Comment: I suspect they mean contemporary _political_ debates and such, not philosophical debates. The first sentence in the quote seems to imply this.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of this sense of "debate"! But I'm not sure that they mean that. "Debate" is sometimes used in philosophy like "problem" or "research field" is used in other disciplines. For example, contributions that discuss free will are sometimes understood as contributions to the "free will debate", and we have many others like the "internalism-externalism debate" or "microfoundations debate".